# Firebase Allow Read/Write Access to All Users Under Any Conditions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I published a basic app several years ago and am now receiving security warnings about open ended write access to my Firebase database.

I understand what the warning means, however, when looking over the instructions to what I need to do, it looks like I am being forced to add authentication to my app.

Ref-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

This app is supposed to be very simple. There is no username/email or authentication. Optionally, I prompt to allow location tracking for the user. This happens at specific moments that the user knowingly triggers in the app to keep track of where they have been and when. I use a device id to differentiate each user.

I am wondering, how can I re-write my current database rules to make Firebase happy, without having to force user authentication? Preferably I would like write permission only to those who have a device id.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

My database looks like this,

[image]

Comment: You should also consider implementing [Firebase anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

Comment: @AlexMamo That is a good idea, although I am trying to avoid any code changes. I am hoping to make a change to the database rules and be done. Like I said, this isn't an Enterprise app. And it is several years old. Do you have any ideas for satisfying Google  without any code updates or app releases?